# How to convert SQLAlchemy TIMESTAMP column read-only buffer to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, sqlalchemy, timestamp, buffer

I have inherited an SQLAlchemy model which interfaces to an MSSQL db.  Most tables have a `modified` column.  The columns are calculated within the db so the model declares them like this:

```
modified = Column(TIMESTAMP, FetchedValue())
```

When I call this property it comes back as a read-only buffer:

```
>>> Thing.modified
<read-only buffer for 0xa901fa0, size 8, offset 0 at 0xa901fc0>

# as a string...
>>> str(Thing.modified)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x85o8'
```

What I need to do is convert it to a `datetime`.  Is this possible?  How?  Any help would be awesome.

Comment: What is the unit of the TIMESTAMP type? Seconds since an epoch?

Comment: @Keith this is what it looks like in MSSQL `0x00000000008346B7`

Comment: According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(v=sql.80).aspx) it's actually a sequence number, in spite of its name. So it's not really a time value at all. It seems to me that it can't be converted to a datetime object.

Comment: @Keith it seems you're correct.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Put your last comment in an answer, if you like, and I'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really an affirmative answer to this question. That data type in MSSQL is actually a sequence number, despite the name. So it's not really possible to convert it to a datetime object.